# Are crosswords on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Can I create simple crosswords (in Latin, of course) and post them as questions on the main site? The correct answer(s) would provide partial or complete solutions to the crossword.

Comment: Do you mean something like [Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), where questions are puzzles and answers are solutions? While more questions would be nice to have, I'm not sure how I feel about questions where the OP is not trying to solve a problem or understand something, but to entertain others with a puzzle. I'd say that such questions are currently off-topic (per SE standard), but of course we can allow them if people want them.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Yes, although I literally mean a [crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crosswords) (filling blank spaces with words), where words are in Latin. Puzzling involves much more than that.

Comment: Then I understood correctly. (And I was indeed sloppy to conflate puzzles with crosswords.) Latin crosswords might be on-topic on Puzzling, but it wouldn't make them off-topic here.